# Resize JTable columns to suit table contents

Tags: java

I used the code pasted below to resize the column width with a delay of 5 seconds once the JTable gets displayed. However, when I run "TestColumnResizer.java", it shows error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError", main not found. How can I modify the code to get it run?Or how can I call the TestColumnResizer program in some other class?

```
public class ColumnResizer {
    public static void adjustColumnPreferredWidths(JTable table) {
        // strategy - get max width for cells in column and
        // make that the preferred width
        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {

            int maxwidth = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
                TableCellRenderer rend = table.getCellRenderer(row, col);
                Object value = table.getValueAt(row, col);
                Component comp = rend.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                        value, false, false, row, col);
                maxwidth = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width, maxwidth);
            } // for row
            TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(col);
            column.setPreferredWidth(maxwidth);
        } // for col
    }
}

// Testing automatic column sizing

public class TestColumnResizer {
    final static Object[][] TABLE_DATA = {
            { new Integer(1), "ONJava", "http://www.onjava.com/" },
            { new Integer(2), "Joshy's Site", "http://www.joshy.org/" },
            { new Integer(3), "Anime Weekend Atlanta",
                    "http://www.awa-con.com/" },
            { new Integer(4), "QTJ book",
                    "http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/quicktimejvaadn/" } };

    final static String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "Count", "Name", "URL" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 142 mac l&f has a header bug - force metal for today
        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                    .getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DefaultTableModel mod = new DefaultTableModel(TABLE_DATA, COLUMN_NAMES);
        JTable table = new JTable(mod);
        JScrollPane pane =

        new JScrollPane(table, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable Column Widths");
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // now get smart about col widths
        final JTable fTable = table;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                ColumnResizer.adjustColumnPreferredWidths(fTable);
                fTable.revalidate();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see there is nothing wrong with the working of the code, just the way the classes are defined.

If this is all in one class file then you are going to get an error. To correct this just edit the class modifiers like this:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

//Testing automatic column sizing
public class TestColumnResizer {
    final static Object[][] TABLE_DATA = {
            { new Integer(1), "ONJava", "http://www.onjava.com/" },
            { new Integer(2), "Joshy's Site", "http://www.joshy.org/" },
            { new Integer(3), "Anime Weekend Atlanta",
                    "http://www.awa-con.com/" },
            { new Integer(4), "QTJ book",
                    "http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/quicktimejvaadn/" } };

    final static String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "Count", "Name", "URL" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 142 mac l&f has a header bug - force metal for today
        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                    .getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DefaultTableModel mod = new DefaultTableModel(TABLE_DATA, COLUMN_NAMES);
        JTable table = new JTable(mod);
        JScrollPane pane =

        new JScrollPane(table, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable Column Widths");
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // now get smart about col widths
        final JTable fTable = table;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                ColumnResizer.adjustColumnPreferredWidths(fTable);
                fTable.revalidate();
            }
        });
    }
}


class ColumnResizer {
    public static void adjustColumnPreferredWidths(JTable table) {
        // strategy - get max width for cells in column and
        // make that the preferred width
        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {

            int maxwidth = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
                TableCellRenderer rend = table.getCellRenderer(row, col);
                Object value = table.getValueAt(row, col);
                Component comp = rend.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                        value, false, false, row, col);
                maxwidth = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width, maxwidth);
            } // for row
            TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(col);
            column.setPreferredWidth(maxwidth);
        } // for col
    }
}
```

If it is not all in one class file than try: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/826/java-exception-in-thread-main-javalangnoclassdeffounderror/. Basically there could be a problem with your classpath.

Don't worry though, the code appears to do everything you specified!